# MongoDB: Fetching documents from different collections in one query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two different collections for two different type of products. Now, I want to fetch all documents from both collections for a particular user.

I know I can do that with 2 queries for each collection, merging them on the server side and sending the result to the user. Downside of this is that I have to fetch all documents for a user from both collections, which is not good for pagination. That is why I want to do it in one query, so I can leave a pagination logic to MongoDB as well.

Here is the example of collections and expected result:

**Products_type_1**

```
[
  {
    "name": "product_1",
    "user": "user_1",
    ...
  },
  {
    "name": "product_2",
    "user": "user_2",
    ...
  }
]
```

**Products_type_2**

```
[
  {
    "name": "product_3",
    "user": "user_1",
    ...
  },
  {
    "name": "product_4",
    "user": "user_2",
    ...
  }
]
```

**The expected result:**

```
[
  {
    "type": "Products_type_1",
    "name": "product_1",
    "user": "user_1",
    ...
  },
  {
    "type": "Products_type_2",
    "name": "product_3",
    "user": "user_1",
    ...
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation framework with [$unionWith](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/) stage:

```
db.Products_type_1.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "user": "user_1"
    }
  },
  {
    $unionWith: {
      coll: "Products_type_2",
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            "user": "user_1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/v0dKCwiKsZU

If you want to use pagination you will need to add sort stage to ensure consistent order of the documents in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would query the logic of having a different collection for the different 'product_type_x'. If you had a single collection with an added field...

```
{ "productType" : 1,
  ...
},
```

That way that issue has just been resolved, everything to do with Procts is now accessible in a single collection. Aggregation of your data now becomes simple (by comparison)